# How to calculate Mean Squared Error when there are multiple observed y values for a single x value?

Tags: regression, anova, residuals, error, mse

Given a data set where there exists multiple different observed y-values for a given x-value, how do I calculate Mean Squared Error? The formula implies that I subtract the predicted from a singular observed value, but what if there is multiple?

Comment: What do you mean there are multiple? Are multiple values linked to a single observation or does it just means that for a given $x$ you happened to have multiple datapoints?

Comment: @Firebug For a given x value, there are multiple data points. i.e. (1,2), (1,3), (1, 5), etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just take the squared error multiple times.

If you have {...,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),...} and you predict y=2 at x=1, the error sum of squares would be

$...+(1-2)^2+(2-2)^2+(3-1)^2+...$

Then, just divide it by the number of observations to get MSE.